# AutoMapper map from collection of IConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I've browsed documentation on mapping collections and nested mapping and mapping of nested collection, but still can't cope with my case.
I have the following json config file:

```
{
  "startupConfig": {
    "noSubscription": {
      "calls": [
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        },
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my code reading from the file:

```
var config = _mapper.Map<FeedConfiguration>(_configuration
    .GetSection("startupConfig").GetChildren()
    .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.Key == "noSubscription")?.GetChildren());
```

However, the mapping does not work. Here is the code of mapping configuration:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>, CallConfiguration>()
    .ForMember(cc => cc.Percentage,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "percentage").Value))
    .ForMember(cc => cc.TechPriority,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "techPriority").Value))
    .ForMember(cc => cc.TimePriority,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "timePriority").Value));
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>, FeedConfiguration>()
    .ForMember(fc => fc.CallsConfig,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "calls").GetChildren()));
```

Classes that I am mapping to:

```
namespace FeedService.FeedConfigurations
{
    public class FeedConfiguration
    {
        public ICollection<CallConfiguration> CallsConfig { get; set; }
    }

    public class CallConfiguration
    {
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public int TechPriority { get; set; }
        public int TimePriority { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is an exception I get:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=============================================================================================================
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
IConfigurationSection -> CallConfiguration (Destination member list)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection -> FeedService.FeedConfigurations.CallConfiguration (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Percentage
TechPriority
TimePriority
```

Would be very thankful for your help!
===Note===
I still need an answer for the question but I posted the new one with better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476564/automapper-map-from-collection-of-iconfigurationsection-with-complex-mapping).

Comment: "Does not work" how?

Comment: Good point, I updated my question, thank you

Comment: Why not use default .net core configuration binding?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk you are right, I can use it easily here.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I updated my question to explain why I didn't use it in the first place with extended example and why I still need AutoMapper

Comment: @VitaliiIsaenko If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I posted a new question for convenience, however, original question is not truly answered while I explicitly asked for mapping with AutoMapper. [New question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476564/automapper-map-from-collection-of-iconfigurationsection-with-complex-mapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need Automepper here. Just use default .net core binding.

rename this one

```
 public ICollection<CallConfiguration> CallsConfig { get; set; }
```

to `Calls`

then use something like

```
 var config  = _configuration.GetSection("startupConfig:noSubscription").Get<FeedConfiguration>();
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you! I would still like to know how to map it with automapper, as my json will change to one that is different from object model that I want to have.

Comment: By the way, maybe you know how to do the same what you described without renaming `CallsConfig` to `Calls`? Maybe I should use some attribute? Would be helpful :)