# AutoMapper map from collection of IConfigurationSection with complex mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

It is my second question on the topic. My first question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475421/automapper-map-from-collection-of-iconfigurationsection/56475821#56475821).
Roman Marusyk provided an easy answer to the question. However, I have more difficult case in reality and it will get even more complex. Therefore, I need to use AutoMapper to map the config (though I would be very happy and surprised if default binding coped with this as well).
Here is my real json with models followed:

```
{
  "startupConfig": {
    "noSubscription": {
      "calls": [
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        },
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        }
      ],
      "profiles": [
        {
          "type": "startup",
          "percentage": 20,
          "techPriority": 2,
          "timePriority": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
namespace FeedService.FeedConfigurations
{
    public class FeedConfiguration
    {
        public ICollection<CallConfiguration> CallsConfig { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProfileConfiguration> ProfilesConfig { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProfileConfiguration
    {
        public CompanyTypeEnum CompanyTypeEnum { get; set; }
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public int TechPriority { get; set; }
        public int TimePriority { get; set; }
    }
    public class CallConfiguration
    {
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public int TechPriority { get; set; }
        public int TimePriority { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here, as you see I need config value of `profiles:type` to be mapped to property with enum type by name. Apparently, default configuration binder does not do magic for me. I also would not like to change type of the property to string or type of the value to integer. Therefore, I still need an answer for the original question for mapping with AutoMapper (where shortened example is enough to extend it for the second part).
===Original question copied for convenience===
I have the following json config file:

```
{
  "startupConfig": {
    "noSubscription": {
      "calls": [
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        },
        {
          "percentage": 30,
          "techPriority": 1,
          "timePriority": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my code reading from the file:

```
var config = _mapper.Map<FeedConfiguration>(_configuration
    .GetSection("startupConfig").GetChildren()
    .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.Key == "noSubscription")?.GetChildren());
```

However, the mapping does not work. Here is the code of mapping configuration:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>, CallConfiguration>()
    .ForMember(cc => cc.Percentage,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "percentage").Value))
    .ForMember(cc => cc.TechPriority,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "techPriority").Value))
    .ForMember(cc => cc.TimePriority,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "timePriority").Value));
CreateMap<IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>, FeedConfiguration>()
    .ForMember(fc => fc.CallsConfig,
        mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "calls").GetChildren()));
```

Classes that I am mapping to:

```
namespace FeedService.FeedConfigurations
{
    public class FeedConfiguration
    {
        public ICollection<CallConfiguration> CallsConfig { get; set; }
    }

    public class CallConfiguration
    {
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public int TechPriority { get; set; }
        public int TimePriority { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is an exception I get:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=============================================================================================================
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
IConfigurationSection -> CallConfiguration (Destination member list)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection -> FeedService.FeedConfigurations.CallConfiguration (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Percentage
TechPriority
TimePriority
```

Would be very thankful for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You can't use AutoMapper to parse Json. Why don't you use a [Json parser](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)?

Comment: I want to use `IConfiguration` and it returns objects of `IConfigurationSection`. Therefore, I don't have json at this point, I work with objects. I will copy parts from the old question to make it clear.

Comment: Please check out the answer to this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687240/map-collection-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile must look like this

```
namespace FeedService.FeedConfigurations
{
    public class FeedConfigurationMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public FeedConfigurationMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<IConfigurationSection, FeedConfiguration>()
                .ForMember(fc => fc.Calls,
                    mo => mo.MapFrom(fc => fc.Get<FeedConfiguration>().Calls));

            CreateMap<IConfigurationSection, CallConfiguration>()
                .ForMember(cc => cc.Percentage,
                    mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "percentage").Value))
                .ForMember(cc => cc.TechPriority,
                    mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "techPriority").Value))
                .ForMember(cc => cc.TimePriority,
                    mo => mo.MapFrom(css => css.GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Key == "timePriority").Value));
        }

    }
}
```

and then use mapper

```
_mapper.Map<FeedConfiguration>(_configuration.GetSection("startupConfig:noSubscription"));
```

> EDIT(additional option)

```
CreateMap<IConfigurationSection, FeedConfiguration>()
                .ForMember(fc => fc.Calls,
                    mo => mo.MapFrom(fc => fc.GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(fd=>fd.Key == "calls").GetChildren()));
```

Comment: It is indeed a good and simple solution, however, I wouldn't like to change the names of the properties of the `FeedConfiguration` class and as I already said the config will get more and more complex later, so I'd prefer fully custom mapping without the default config binding. Thank you anyway!